# SSRS date parameters not displaying data in report for non-null values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, reporting-services, parameters

I have 4 parameters in my report of which 2 are date parameters - Startdate and Enddate.

My req is to list and select all values in parameters, I created datasets to include NULL values for Startdate using `if(Parameters!StartDate.Value is nothing,"1/1/1900",Parameters!StartDate.Value)`

I am seeing correct list of values for Start date(includes null values) and Target date while running report.

Report runs fine if I select Start date(e.g: 2013-12-20) and Target date(2013-12-16).

But If I select "NULL" Start date and Corresponding Target date report is blank whereas I should see data.

```
Start Date  Target Date
NULL            2016-02-26
2013-12-20  2013-12-16
NULL            2016-04-01
2014-12-12  2014-12-04
```

Any help/suggestions is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: I don't understand this sentence:  "But If I select non-null Start date(i.e any date) and Target date but when I select NULL Start date and Corresponding Target date report is blank whereas I should see data."  Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I see you are replacing `NULL` values for `"1/1/1900"` string. Is your parameter date type or text?

Comment: Parameter data type is DATE/TIME

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if you select `NULL` for `StartDate` parameter? Maybe show values from "1/1/1900"?

Comment: Why do you think you should see data if you select NULL for Start Date?  I think you're going to have to show a lot more about what your data is, what your dataset queries are, how your parameters are set up, etc.

Comment: Please take a look at the queries I am using:http://pastebin.com/raw/3jw5ArQ5